# WooCommerce get_price returning wrong price when used via ajax

Tags: plugins, php, plugin-development, theme-development, ajax

I'm working on a site that uses the Events Tickets plugin, and I need to get the price of a ticket (Woo product) by ID. I'm using `wc_get_product( $ticketID )->get_price();` to to do this.

Adding the price to the page using the code below gives the correct price (e.g. 30):

```
echo '<input type="hidden" id="ticketpricetest" value="' . wc_get_product( 28612 )->get_price() . '">';
```

However, when I try and get the price using the same method within an Ajax call it returns 300:

```
function get_ticket_price() {
  $ticketID = $_REQUEST['ticketID'];
  echo wc_get_product( $ticketID )->get_price();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_ticket_price', 'get_ticket_price' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ticket_price', 'get_ticket_price' );
```

I've also tried using `get_regular_price` but that also returns 300.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Are you certain `$ticketID` is correct? Are you passing it as an integer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to exit the function when using the [wp_ajax hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_ajax_action/). Hopefully this fixes it.

```
function get_ticket_price() {
  $ticketID = $_REQUEST['ticketID'];
  echo wc_get_product( $ticketID )->get_price();

  // Don't forget to stop execution afterward.
  wp_die();
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_get_ticket_price', 'get_ticket_price' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_get_ticket_price', 'get_ticket_price' );
```